# Heroku deploy chat bot

Tags: heroku, bots

so, my code works both locally and docker image but, when I deploy to heroku it seems to work on first 1 minute and then app crashes, there is [heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL4Ki.png), after crashing so what can be problems? any thought? thank you

there is my code

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios')
const telegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()

const links = `
<a href="https://git.foxminded.com.ua/foxstudent100709">GitLab</a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/elguja-mtchedlidze-39a746225/">Linkdin</a>
<a href="https://mtchedlidze-87ef7.web.app/">Personal</a>
  `
const bot = new telegramBot(process.env.TOKEN, { polling: true })
const aboutText = 'Hello, I am learning NODE JS!'
const app = express()
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  const id = message.chat.id

  if (message.text === '/start' || message.text === '/help') {
    bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, 'avalable commands', {
      reply_markup: {
        keyboard: [['/about', '/links']],
        resize_keyboard: true,
        one_time_keyboard: true,
        force_reply: true,
      },
    })
  } else if (message.text === '/about') {
    bot.sendMessage(id, aboutText)
  } else if (message.text === '/links') {
    bot.sendMessage(id, links, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
  } else {
    bot.sendMessage(
      message.chat.id,
      'no such command! there are avalable commands',
      {
        reply_markup: {
          keyboard: [['/about', '/links']],
          resize_keyboard: true,
          one_time_keyboard: true,
          force_reply: true,
        },
      }
    )
  }
})
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --production

COPY ./app.js .

ENV port=8080
ENV TOKEN=21*****:AAEF******************fKiQ
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app fails to bind to the port assigned by Heroku: you cannot set the port yourself (ie 8080) but instead bind to the port defined by the `$PORT` env variable.

See [Why is my Node.js app crashing with an R10 error?](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) to understand the details.

In your specific case if you run the Bot in `polling` mode (i.e. pulling the changes) you can instead use a `worker` node instead of a `web`: doing this you don't need to bind to the port as your application does not require to process incoming HTTP requests.